# How to display the Byte stream values in java console

Tags: java, stream

I know that in Java we have byte streams and character streams. The confusion is how to display the byte value directly in the output statements.

For example, I am typing my name in console, then using:

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)) ;
String name=br.readLine();
```

If I display the name I get the value which I have typed. How can I display it in byte value?

Comment: Which bytes? Using which encoding? Hint: See the documentation for the `getBytes()` function on strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean raw bytes:

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)) ;
String name=br.readLine();

System.out.write(name.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Note that the output depends on the specific encoding you choose (in this case, UTF-8).

If you wanted to print a readable hex value for each byte, you will have to work a bit on the code above, but it should be straighforward.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for UTF-8 encoded bytes:

```
byte [] bytes = name.getBytes("UTF-8");
for( int i=0; i < bytes.length ;++i)
    System.out.println(bytes[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the UTF-8 byte values as Hex (a convenient way for representing raw byte data as a String) you can do this.

```
String name=br.readLine();
String nameUTF8Hex = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(name.getBytes("UTF-8"));
System.out.println(nameUTF8Hex);
```

Details for [`DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#printHexBinary%28byte%5B%5D%29)